# Baccarat big eye rod in Javafx tableview

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm creating a the game of Baccarat using Javafx. I have succeed mostly but I'm stuck in showing the big eye rod map, which will look like the image below.

**Big Eye Rod**

[image]

I'm trying to display the outcomes in `TabelView` Control. Since the `TableColumn` in are dynamically added (based on the hand outcome), I'm not sure how to define the data model for the `TableView`.

Can some one guide me to define a data model for this purpose.

Comment: Seems like you need a fixed size board without column resizing/autoscrolling... I recommend using a `GridPane` instead of a `TableView`

Comment: That might work thanks for your view.